# Google Analytics - How to see views by geography (location) by hour

Tags: google-analytics, report, geography

I am looking to see what time of day people in certain countries/continents viewed my website.  For example, an hourly report of only Asia.  I know how to do an hourly report and also by geography but not together.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's specific to reporting. This should be posted to Webmasters instead.

Comment: what is webmasters?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/